# Use of editActionsForRowAt on a tableView with sections in Swift 3

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I´m new in this of Swift 3 so I need some help please.
I did a tableView where have 3 different sections. In each section, the number of rows is variable depending results from a query (Parse)

It works great, even at selecting to segue and see details of each one. But here is my issue: I would like to delete by swipe some cell in second section. So here is my code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
switch indexPath.section {
        case 0:
            return nil
        case 1:
            switch indexPath.row {
            case 0...myArray.count
            let myObjectToDelete = myArray[indexPath.row]

                let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Borrar") { (action, indexPath) in
                    let query = PFQuery(className: "Things")
                    query.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: objectID!)
                    query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) in
                        if error != nil {
                            print((error?.localizedDescription)!)
                        } else {
                            if let objects = objects {
                                for object in objects {
                                    object.deleteInBackground()

  /* ISSUE HERE    */ myArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
  /* ISSUE HERE    */ self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

                                }
                            }

                        }
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    })
                }
                return [deleteAction]
            default:
                break
            }

        case 2:
            shareAction
        default:
            break
            }
        default:
            break
        }
}
```

At the middle, after delete the object in background what does well, I mark 2 ISSUES. At tableView the cell I had delete, doesn't disappear, but other cells yes.

So, how can I solve that? Thanks a lot